# Kali linux bootable drive on a USB

Tags: linux, boot, usb

I just started my security class, and we're using kali linux on virtual box at school. Now my question is could i plug in a usb stick with kali on it and just boot it up on any computers that's got Virtual box? And if so how could i do it? And will the files i created stay on the kali linux thats on my usb stick or will tey just dissapear once i connect it back to virtual box on my computer at home ?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a virtual machine on a removable drive.

However, the version of Vbox on your target machine needs to be the same version as your own system. (Vbox Extension versions for example).

Some computers may be set up to disallow foreign USB keys. The target computer may have a standard User ID which also may present an issue.

So while this idea might be theoretically possible, there are roadblocks which may stop you.